# Debugging "Managed memory leak detected" in Spark 1.6.0

Tags: apache-spark

I've tried upgrading to Apache Spark 1.6.0 RC3. My application now spams these errors for nearly every task:

```
Managed memory leak detected; size = 15735058 bytes, TID = 830
```

I've set logging level for `org.apache.spark.memory.TaskMemoryManager` to `DEBUG` and see in the logs:

```
I2015-12-18 16:54:41,125 TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 6, localhost, partition 0,NODE_LOCAL, 3026 bytes)
I2015-12-18 16:54:41,125 Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 6)
I2015-12-18 16:54:41,130 ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 1 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
I2015-12-18 16:54:41,130 ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
D2015-12-18 16:54:41,188 TaskMemoryManager: Task 6 acquire 5.0 MB for null
I2015-12-18 16:54:41,199 ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 1 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
I2015-12-18 16:54:41,199 ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
D2015-12-18 16:54:41,262 TaskMemoryManager: Task 6 acquire 5.0 MB for null
D2015-12-18 16:54:41,397 TaskMemoryManager: Task 6 release 5.0 MB from null
E2015-12-18 16:54:41,398 Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 5245464 bytes, TID = 6
```

How do you debug these errors? Is there a way to log stack traces for allocations and deallocations, so I can find what leaks?

I don't know much about the new unified memory manager ([SPARK-10000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10000)). Is the leak likely my fault or is it likely a Spark bug?

Comment: did you try to run with your logger set on DEBUG Level?

Comment: Thanks! I've now run with `<logger name="org.apache.spark.memory.TaskMemoryManager" level="DEBUG" />` and allocations and deallocations are logged. Still have no idea what's happening though :). I'll add more details in a bit.

Comment: I've added the logs. There are two 5MB `acquire` calls and just one 5MB `release` call. But why?

Comment: Are you working with dataframes? I started getting a rash of these kind of errors when trying to manipulate dataframes. The memory leak appears to be associated with the Java process, which continually sucks up more memory as the application runs.

Comment: No, this is without DataFrames. I don't think it's a Java thing. This is logged by Spark's memory manager where the task can acquire and release memory explicitly. The task ends but something is left unreleased. The memory manager releases this automatically, but logs this warning to let us know something is bugged.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The short answer is that users are not supposed to see this message. Users are not supposed to be able to create memory leaks in the unified memory manager.

That such leaks happen is a Spark bug: [SPARK-11293](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11293)

---

But if you want to understand the cause of a memory leak, this is how I did it.

1. Download the Spark source code and make sure you can build it and your build works.
2. In `TaskMemoryManager.java` add extra logging in `acquireExecutionMemory` and `releaseExecutionMemory`: `logger.error("stack trace:", new Exception());`
3. Change all the other debug logs to error in `TaskMemoryManager.java`. (Easier than figuring out logging configurations...)

Now you will see the full stack trace for all allocations and deallocations. Try to match them up and find the allocations without deallocations. You now have the stack trace for the source of the leak.

Comment: I saw this exception while running spark streaming on EMR 

16/04/14 13:49:10 WARN memory.TaskMemoryManager: leak 32.3 MB memory from org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@34158d5f
16/04/14 13:49:10 ERROR executor.Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 33816576 bytes, TID = 2942915
16/04/14 13:49:10 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 22.0 in stage 35684.0 (TID 2942915)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 262144 bytes of memory, got 220032

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am facing a similar issue of memory leak in spark 1.6.2

Comment: I think in my case it was [SPARK-14560](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14560). It is fixed in Spark 2.0.0 and we are using 2.1.0 now, so all is good.

Comment: does all these comment mean, if I can not upgrade to the 'good' version yet due to company IT readiness, I can safely ignore the error?  
I am currently using spark 1.6.0 and having errors like this when some dataframe does 'distinct' and then 'head'.

Comment: Well, if ignoring it is your only option, I suggest you ignore it :). It may lead to out-of-memory issues, being a warning about memory mis-accounting.

Comment: We're seeing it on spark 2.3.1. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Could be a bug! I'd file a JIRA issue about it and see if somebody can track it down.

Comment: For newer versions of Spark see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526122/spark-2-3-memory-leak-on-executor

Answer (score 1):

I found this warn message too, but it was cause by "df.repartition(rePartNum,df("id"))".
My df is empty, and the warn message's line equals to rePartNum.
version:
spark2.4
win10