# Spark 1.6.1: Memory Leak Messages with Mesos

Tags: apache-spark

I am have a dataframe that calls an UDF like the following:

```
val myUDF = udf ((x:Int) => {
  val t = new Array[Integer](4)
  .. processing .. 
  })
```

This UDF is being called 20 million times as part of a column operation. When I run the above function as part of `Mesos framework` `(v 0.28)` with `8G` executor memory, I get the following memory leak message:

```
11/08/12 11:18:13 ERROR Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 67371008 bytes, TID = 10
11/08/12 11:18:13 WARN TaskMemoryManager: leak 64.3 MB memory from org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@7b56b8b7
```

If the Array is being instantiated 20 million times, then my memory requirement (for this specific UDF) is not more that `20*128`MB i.e. `2.6GB`. The failure always failues with `64.3 MB` leak which makes me think that this is being enforced somewhere.

How do I get around this? I have already tried Spark releases 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging "Managed memory leak detected" in Spark 1.6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359211/debugging-managed-memory-leak-detected-in-spark-1-6-0)

Comment: I get the same errors with 1.6.0, 1,6.1, 1.6.2.