# Spark scala most frequent item in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with 4 columns that looks like this: (Columns 1 - name, 2- title, 3- views, 4 - size)

```
aa Droomstele 1 8030
aa Wikiquote 1 78261
aa Special 1 20493
aa.b Droomstele 7 4749
aa.b Droomstele 1 4751
af Blowback 2 16896
af Bluff 2 21442
en Bloubok 1 0
```

I want to select the most frequently occurring title (based on Column Title).
The output should be:
`Droomstele` 
 as it occurs 3 times in the data.

How do I go ahead with grouping the titles and then taking the max count from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

Given this input RDD:

```
var input = sc
  .parallelize(Array(
    "aa Droomstele 1 8030",
    "aa Wikiquote 1 78261",
    "aa Special 1 20493",
    "aa.b Droomstele 7 4749",
    "aa.b Droomstele 1 4751",
    "af Blowback 2 16896",
    "af Bluff 2 21442",
    "en Bloubok 1 0"
  ))
  .map(row => row.split(" "))
```

The following returns `Droomstele`:

```
input.map(split => (split(1), 1)) // RDD[("Droomstele", 1), ...]
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)             // RDD[..., ("Droomstele", 3), ...]
  .sortBy(_._2)                   // RDD[("Droomstele", 3), ...] (Droomstele is first)
  .first                          // ("Droomstele", 3)
  ._1                             // "Droomstele"
```

---

Alternatively, and slightly faster:

```
input.map(split => (split(1), 1))                 // RDD[("Droomstele", 1), ...]
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)                             // RDD[..., ("Droomstele", 3), ...]
  .takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(_._2)) // Array[("Droomstele", 3)]
  .head                                           // ("Droomstele", 3)
  ._1                                             // "Droomstele"
```

Comment: I got this Managed memory leak detected; size = 5281848 bytes. Could you suggest a more efficient method since my data file is quite large.

Comment: Not sure why; this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359211/debugging-managed-memory-leak-detected-in-spark-1-6-0