# Spark 2.3 Memory Leak on Executor

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, memory-leaks, pyspark

I am getting memory leak warning which ideally was a Spark bug back till 1.6 version and was resolved.

Mode: Standalone
IDE: PyCharm
Spark version: 2.3
Python version: 3.6

Below is the stack trace -

```
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3148
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3152
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3151
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3150
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3149
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3153
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3154
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3158
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3155
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3157
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3160
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3161
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3156
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3159
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3165
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3163
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3162
2018-05-25 15:00:05 WARN  Executor:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 3166
```

Any insight on why it may happen? Though my job is successfully getting accomplished.

Edit: Many said it is duplicate of the 2 years old question, but the answer there says it was a Spark bug but when checked in Spark's Jira, it says it is resolved.

Question here is, so many versions later, why am I still getting the same in Spark 2.3? I'll surely remove the question if it seems really redundant with some valid or logical answer to my query.

Comment: you mush have left some use of resources open like connection to database or opening a file and forgot to close etc

Comment: That's not the case here, Ramesh.

Comment: I am seeing something similar.  I even see the exact same byte value (262144 bytes), though I'm using scala. Have you had any luck debugging this?

Comment: @Aakash Basu, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

According to [SPARK-14168](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14168?jql=text%20~%20%22managed%20memory%20leak%20detected%22), the warning stems from not consuming an entire iterator. I have encountered the same error when taking n elements from an RDD in Spark shell.